# Creating a table in django from a list of lists

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-3.5, django-1.9

So, I'm trying to make a table that looks something like this:

```
Thing/Person | PersonA                    | PersonB
ThingA       | [green]PersonA[/green]     | [red]PersonB[/red]
ThingB       | [red]PersonA[/red]         | [green]PersonB[/green]
```

Each "person" has a primary key pointing to a "thing", "Person.thing". If a person is related to multiple things, there are multiple entries with the same .name value in the database. In the view, I attenpt to make a list of lists, containing an html-coloured version of the person's name. Green if they have a relation, and red if they do not:

```
persons_list = Persons.objects.all()
context_dict["persons"] = persons_list

persons_list_nodups = Persons.objects.values_list('name', flat=True).distinct()
context_dict["persons_nodups"] = persons_list_nodups

things_list = Things.objects.order_by("-title")
context_dict["things"] = things_list

listOfRelationsToThings = []

a = ""
b = ""
c = []
lineyes = '<font color="green">  </font>'
lineno = '<font color="red">  </font>'
indexyes = lineyes.find(" </font>")
indexno = lineno.find(" </font>")
i = 0
number_of_persons = len(persons_list_nodups)
for thing in things_list:
    for person in persons_list_nodups:
        if i == len(persons_list_nodups):
            listOfRelationsToThings.append(c)
            c = []
            i = 0
        for person2 in persons_list:
            if person2.name == person1 and person2.thing == thing:
                a = lineyes[:indexyes] + person1 + lineyes[indexyes:]
                break
            else:
                b = lineno[:indexno] + person1 + lineno[indexno:]
        i = i + 1
        if a == "":
            c.append(b)
        else:
            c.append(a)
            a = ""

context_dict["listOfListsOfRelationsToThings"] = listOfRelationsToThings
```

In the template, I then iterate over this list, trying to print only the legnth of persons_list_nodups number of names per row:

```
            <tr>
                <th>Things/Persons</th>
              {% for person in persons_nodups %}
                <th>{{ person }}</th>
              {% endfor %}
            </tr>
              {% for thing in things %}
                <tr>
                <th>{{ thing }}</th>
                    {% for i in listOfListsOfRelationsToThings %}
                        {% for relation in i %}
                            {{ context_var|safe }}
                            {% autoescape off %}
                                <td>{{ relation }}<td>
                            {% endautoescape %}
                        {% endfor %}
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
              {% endfor %}
```

But in the end, the pattern looks like this, meaning it only prints the first row, but two times, along with an empty space for some reason:

```
Thing/Person | PersonA                | PersonB           |
ThingA       | [green]PersonA[/green] |                   | [red]PersonB[/red]
ThingB       | [green]PersonA[/green] |                   | [red]PersonB[/red]
```

The values in the database are correct, so what am I doing wrong??

Comment: Instead of having a number of duplicate entries for `Person` objects, each pointing to a different `Thing`, have you considered putting a ForeignKey field on `Thing` pointing to `Person`? (Or a ManyToManyField if that's what you need?)